# Ticktext not shown in plotly choropleth map

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to have the values associated to my colorbarscale in my plotly figure map, I tried setting the tickvals and ticktext values but it is not shown in the figure. Here is my code, if you can help me figure out how to display the text of the colorbar legend:

```
fig = px.density_mapbox(df, lat='y', lon='x', z='patient_count', 
                        radius=5,
                        center=dict(lat=48.8566, lon=2.3522), # Center on Paris
                        zoom=5
                        )

fig.update_layout(
    width=1400,
    height=800,
    mapbox=dict(
        style="carto-positron", 
    ),
    margin={"r":150, "t":30, "l":30, "b":30}, 
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
        title='Number of Patients',
        tickvals=[0, 15000, 30000, 45000, 60000],
        ticktext=['0', '15k', '30k', '45k', '60k']
    )
)


fig.show()
```

I tried to simplify the code of my figure and also work with the coloraxis_colorbar features like len, thickness, x and y values to manually set the colorbar in the figure.